# What happens if I demolish a mobile home with an outstanding loan?

Tags: united-states, loans, home

I own a double wide manufactured home that is desperate need of repairs. Parts of the floor are  falling through, the central air doesn't work, and I recently discovered black mold inside the walls.

I feel that trying to repair this home is going to cost much more than I'm  willing to spend.

I still owe money on this home and land. Would the bank complain if I demolished  this home and moved a new one  to my lot or built a new one in its place?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag. Also how much was the original loan, what is the current outstanding. How are you planning to finance the build up of new home

Comment: Banks tend to operate on contracts in such matters. Does your contract prohibit it?

Comment: I cant add any more tags because it says I need 300 Reputation. But to answer your question, Im from the United States.

Comment: Seems a dupe with https://money.stackexchange.com/q/98806/17714

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in the comments to the question, the specifics of what is or is not allowed would be in your mortgage documents.

Generally speaking, this wouldn't be allowed. The home is part of the collateral the bank is using to allow you to borrow their money. What if you tear it down, don't rebuild, and default on the loan? Even if it's in dire shape, it may still be worth *something*. Mortgages are loans provided to people on the premise that the collateral is in place to cover the balance of the loan should you cease payment. That collateral was agreed upon when you signed for the mortgage, and now you want to change it. Even if you're going to build a house that's worth 5x more, the original terms of the mortgage are no longer valid.

Many mortgages also have clauses that require that a home be maintained to a certain standard. If that maintenance hasn't been taken care of, leading to the home being in a situation where it could be condemned, they could foreclose on the entire property to get as much of their money back as possible.

There are some differences between what's considered a large renovation versus a complete demolition and rebuild and types of refinancing that can be available to cover them. You may need to research what constitutes it in your area or in your mortgage agreement. For instance, if the foundation is still in place, but the structure is replaced, that might be a large renovation. If everything is torn up, that's a rebuild. (This is not definitive, just an example of things to look into.) With the type of home you're describing, I don't know if that would apply. Although you might not need the money from a construction mortgage, it could put you in the proper place with the bank regarding agreements on collateral vs mortgage amount.

When reviewing the collateral value for your mortgage, maybe the land is worth enough by itself to cover the requirements, and replacing the home doesn't matter. It may be worth getting an appraisal to consider that.